# Tikz Error: Use of parabola doesn't match it's definition

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to create a Beamer presentation template from an existing example, and am having trouble with the following lines of code within my "beamerinnertheme.sty file:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{background}{Custom theme}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax %not the title page
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}] (0,8) rectangle (0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette secondary}] (0.9,8) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \else% Title page
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}] (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
        \path[fill stretch image =img/wave_blue_aqua_4c] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,3);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The  resulting error I get is as follows:

```
! Use of \tikz@parabola doesn't match its definition.
\beamer@@tmpl@background ...sebeamercolor [bg]{pal
ette primary}] (0,0) recta...
```

What am I doing wrong?  The error comes from the where the title page background fill is specified:

```
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}] (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
```

If this line is commented, the error goes away.  I have tried using simple numbers instead of the `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` variables, as well as different specifiers for the bottom left corner of the rectangle (other than `(0,0`), but neither of these solved the issue.

It seems to be a syntax error, but for the life of me, I cannot see where that is the case.

## EDIT:

Here is a minimal example:

`beamerinnerthememycustomtheme.sty`:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\newenvironment{xplainframe}{\bgroup\setbeamertemplate{background}{}\begin{frame}[plain]}{\end{frame}\egroup}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mycustomtheme theme}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax %not the title page
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}] (0,8) rectangle (0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette secondary}] (0.9,8) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \else% Title page
        \fill[color=\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}] (0,2.5) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\mode
<all>
```

`beamerthememycustomtheme.sty`:

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\useinnertheme{mycustomtheme}

\mode
<all>
```

`example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{mycustomtheme} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\author{Author}
\title{Presentation Title}
\institute{My University}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\maketitle}
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{First Slide}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\begin{itemize}
\item First sub item
\begin{itemize}
\item First sub sub item
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: An obvious problem is that `[bg]` stops reading the optional argument to `\fill`; however, `\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette secondary}` doesn't directly expand to a color specification, so using `color={\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette secondary}}` doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The puzzling error is due to the `]` in the optional argument to `\fill` so it *should* be

```
\fill[color={\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}}]
```

with braces to protect the `]`. However this doesn't work, because the construct

```
\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}
```

doesn't directly expand to a color name, but it does so only after a long sequence of operations that include assignments.

A way out is to obtain the color indirectly:

```latex
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[circle]

\newenvironment{xplainframe}
  {\bgroup\setbeamertemplate{background}{}\begin{frame}[plain]}
  {\end{frame}\egroup}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox0{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}\xglobal\colorlet{paletteprimary}{.}}%
  \sbox0{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette secondary}\xglobal\colorlet{palettesecondary}{.}}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background}{mycustomtheme theme}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \ifnum\value{page}>1\relax %not the title page
        \fill[color=paletteprimary] (0,8) rectangle (0.8,8.3);
        \fill[color=palettesecondary] (0.9,8) rectangle (\the\paperwidth, 8.3);
  \else% Title page
        \fill[color=paletteprimary] (0,0) rectangle (\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
  \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\mode
<all>
```

However, if I compile the example file with this modified theme file, I get no output, because apparently `palette primary` and `palette secondary` both point to white. You will need to define your own version of the colors.

Note that the last `\fill` should have `(0,0)`, rather than `(0,2.5)`.

Comment: Yes this works.  Thank you.  When I remove the ```\usebeamercolor``` command from the option specifier everything is OK.  You are right about the colors it makes more sense when I use my own color template.